# Searching through XHR requests on Chrome with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to gather JSON information from a website, and in order to do that, I need a key that changes whenever you log back in.

I can find this key by using Dev Tools --> Network then there is an XHR request with the key in it. I can easily find the key manually, but is there a way I can find it using JavaScript?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it's possible, though it would be more elegant to figure out where the key is coming from and getting the value directly from that, instead of intercepting network requests. (Might be possible, might not be - if not, then you can try to monkeypatch the request method they're using)

Comment: I suppose I could try that, and I agree that it would be much more efficient to do that, but if it would even be possible it would take a lot of time and I'm just doing this project for fun and don't really care about efficiency. How do you think I would go about searching the requests?

Comment: Can you figure out the request method used? `XMLHttpRequest`, or `fetch`, or jQuery?

Comment: It looks like it's using jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to run a script that either modifies the jQuery object before the request runs, or you'll have to run a script before the page loads that loads the global jQuery object itself, and prevents it from being reassigned. Once you do that, you can then modify `jQuery.get` or whichever jQuery function the site is using, to get it to give you its information whenever it's called, like so:

```js
const oldGet = jQuery.get;
jQuery.get = function(...args) {
  if (args[1]) {
    const data = args[1];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  }
  oldGet.apply(this, args);
}



// then once the native script calls $.get, or whichever method, it will go through your custom function first:



$.get('/someendpoint', { authKey: 'abcde' });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```